# Mirroring PS4 to PC without capture card

Tags: ps4, streaming, ps-remote-play

I want to mirror my PS4 output to my PC (actually Mac, but I can boot Windows if necessary) so I can add an overlay and stream to Twitch.  I'm aware of the Remote Play option to access the PS4 via LAN, which works fine for me except for one detail: I have to connect a controller to the PC, and not the PS4.  This apparently requires me to buy a special dongle to connect the DS4 to my Mac, which is not ideal.  Also, I'm worried about controller latency having to route through my computer and over the network to the PS4.

Are there any other options or some kind of setting for Remote Play that would just let it mirror the game output to my PC, while playing the game on the TV with the DS4 connected directly to the PS4?

Comment: Actually, you can just connect your controller with a regular USB cable, assuming your Mac has a USB port. No need for any "special dongles".

Comment: That’s one thing I neglected to mention, I have charging adapters glued to the USB ports on my controllers so a cable is a pain too.  Lag is the primary reason I want to avoid connecting the controller to the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I use remote play to stream and the only better option is having a capture card tank all the bandwidth and modulate a medium for streaming all audio and game amd music etc